# Android App alternate Market or place

Tags: android, google-play

I just finished my App and is now in the market, so far so good, in fact the name is DopeWars Underground (just in case you wanted to see it) my question is, there is another place to promote that App outside of the Android Market to advertise this App ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what's already been said, you could also publish it on competing/alternate marketplaces, such as http://slideme.org/, http://andappstore.com/ and http://www.insydemarket.com/ - they're smaller than the android marketplace, potentially giving your app more exposure.

I noticed your app is 9.5mb; it might deter many potential users from trying the application; especially if they're running on android < 2.2 - almost 10mb of data is a considerable chunk of the available ram. I'd recommend storing the media assets on the sd-card instead (download them from within the app).

Lastly, there are forums where you can promote your apps, such as http://androidforums.com/application-announcements/ and http://www.anddev.org/promote-your-android-application-f22/

Answer (score 3):

There are several alternative markets for Android. In descending order of install counts I have seen for my apps:

1. [SlideMe](http://slideme.org)
2. [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b?ie=UTF8&node=2350149011)
3. [GetJar](http://www.getjar.com)
4. [AppsLib](http://www.appslib.com)
5. http://andappstore.com
6. http://www.insydemarket.com
7. http://www.nduoa.com (Chinese)

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to advertising applications I take a three or four step approach depending on the app.

1. (optional) Create a website for your application.
2. Create a myspace/facebook/blog/twitter account for your app. Use them to spread the good word.
3. Post videos of your app online through vimeo / youtube / etc.
4. Submit your app info to various blogs / tech reviewers. Ask them politely to consider giving it an online review.

Comment: could you please provide me a couple of tech reviewers sites?

Answer (score 0):

The best you might do is to ask some special resources specializing in mobile apps review to make a review of your app.
 
Search for special resources which are popular in your country. 
May be it will be useful to promote your app in social networks in special groups - there must be a group for android fans in facebook.