# Can you please me some free android market

Tags: android, google-play

HI all,
 I want to publish my android app in the market. But in official market.android.com, its been mentioned as $25 as registration fee. Is there any android market which is free to publish...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944205/android-app-alternate-market-or-place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also [Andspot](http://andspot.com/) and [Pdassi](http://android.pdassi.com). I haven't tried the second one but I uploaded my app to the first and haven't gotten a single download from it.
You can also just put your app on a website with a download.
The problem with all of these options is that they aren't nearly as visible as the android market and you wont get nearly as many people using your app.

Answer (score 1):

Publish at www.androidpit.com you can create a free developers account.

Answer (score 1):

please [check this](https://developer.amazon.com/apps/main.html) that may be free for first year.

so your problem may be solved.